# Is there a way to read a SQL query by ignoring the column name in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Say I have to read a column from my SQL server DB into a dataframe using:

```
query = 'select urls from table1'

df = pd.read_sql_query(query,connection)
```

My `df` looks like this:

[image: screenshot of <code>df</code>]

I am trying to get the response code of these URLs by passing through a loop like this -

```
response_list = []
for x in df:
  response = requests.get(x)
  response_list.append(response)

print(response_list)
```

> Error Message: Invalid URL 'URLs': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://URLs?

The column name is also being passed if I try to loop the df.
Is there a way to ignore the column name and just have the values?
Or suggest a way to loop through for by ignoring the column name.

Comment: Not clear what you're after. Try [`iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html).

Comment: does [`index_col` parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html) help you?

Comment: Hi @CHRD, I have a df which I have read from a SQL query. It comes with its relevant column name. When I pass the df through a loop, the column(header) name also gets passed which I dont want. Slicing also doesn't help. Do you have any alternate options? Is it now clear what I am after?

Comment: Hi @NikosM., I tried but it does not help. Thanks but do let me know if you have other options.

Comment: @BharathwajMurali see my answer below. You need `for x in df.yourColumn.values`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question, I assume you have a dataframe with one column like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1, 2, 3]})
```

If you want to loop through the rows and use the values you can simply:

```
for i in df.col.values: print('Something' + str(i))
```

**EDIT**: based on the updated question, change your loop to:

```
for x in df['URLs'].values:
  response = requests.get(x)
  response_list.append(response)
```